# Ajax auto updates and server load

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have a project that needs a sort of shopping cart that is always available at the top of the screen. Whenever someone hovers over the "cart" icon, a list of everything that's inside is shown.
However, if an user has two tabs of my site open, and in one of them something is added to the cart, the other one will be outdated and a refresh will be required.

My question is: if I use AJAX to constantly update the list of items (which will require sessions and database checks), will it be a big enough load on the server (or even on the browser) for it to be a problem, or is this common practice? If it is a problem, what other ways can I go so every tab an user opens is always updated?

If someone could show me the path so I can study more about it, even the name of what I should look up, I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no load on browser, just one more request in server ... maybe these requests are useless,

there is another way name `server push`

- APE (Ajax Push Engine) :: Comet server :: Real time data streaming ->
  http://www.ape-project.org/
- nginx_http_push_module - Comet For The People -> http://pushmodule.slact.net/
- node.js -> http://www.nodejs.org/
- Socket.IO: the cross-browser WebSocket for realtime apps. ->
  http://socket.io/
- Comet with Nginx and jQuery | Coach J ->
  http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/

if your request count is more than your server power use this way but if you have little request and not important you can use server pull frequently

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is the solution here - it has a very light footprint.. as long as you don't use it indiscriminately, it is pretty much the same as reloading the page (much less if done correctly as its serving a smaller document). In fact, research has shown that ajax can cut the server bandwidth usage by over 60%.

You can read about the speed issue specifically [here](http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/ajax-bandwidth-testing/).

I learned Ajax over at Tizag, they have a brilliant [Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/).

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

you can make the ajax call on an interval to load the div with latest data. Something like this

```
(function getLatestCart(){  
   setTimeout(function(){   
      $("#latestCart").load("getCartDetails.php", getLatestCart);     
  }, 10000);  
})();
```

this will call the method on every 10 sec(you can change the time interval) and load the latest cart to the div with id `latestCart`.

Answer (score 0):

You can track locally this changes.

Use UserData (IE7 and down) or domStorage with updated data, and check every 10-20 seconds if the data was changed.